# Current Consumption of multiplexed 7 segment

Tags: current, 7segmentdisplay

I have a display with an one digit 7 segment , I want to use a multiplexed seven-segment and my regulator can just support 150ma of current .
Now my question is that.
Is the current that the regulator must supply the same for both modes? Does it mean that whether it provides for one or  for matrixed segment is ​​the same?
Because practically every moment a digit is lit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need enough average current per 'on' segment for it to be adequately bright. So if you have 4 digits multiplexed you'd need around 4x the current for a single digit that is driven statically.

The average current required for a display to be adequately bright depends on the LED dice, the display design, optical filters, operating conditions etc. Multiplexing generally does not affect the total required current much. In other words, if 5mA per  segment is adequate there will not be much visual difference between a statically driven display showing 8.8.8.8. and drawing 160mA and one driven with 20mA per segment and 25% duty cycle (also 160mA from the power supply).

Answer (score 1):

> *Is the current that the regulator must supply the same for both modes?*

and

> *Does it mean that whether it provides for one or for matrixed segment
> is ​​the same?*

Theoretically yes; in practice it's a wee bit higher (but not much).